# Change String to Float Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I would like to convert a list that I took out from a txt file into a float so I can make some calculous after in Python. I have the following list:

```
['1,0,1.2', '2,-1.5,1.2', '3,-1.5,0', '4,0,0', '5,1.5,1.2']
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
[1,0,1.2,2,-1.5,1.2,3,-1.5,0,4,0,0,5,1.5,1.2]
```

All of them being float type.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to iterate over the strings in the list, split each string by the commas and convert each number-string to a float. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: that looks like CSV, maybe you should be using the `csv` module, or maybe pandas to read it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two loops are needed here, an outer for the array and an inner loop over the spitted strings.

```
>>> new = [float(v) for inner in a for v in inner.split(",")]
>>> new
[1.0, 0.0, 1.2, 2.0, -1.5, 1.2, 3.0, -1.5, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.5, 1.2]
```

EDIT:
To up it to accept any case, differentiate between int/float for example:

```py
    >>> from ast import literal_eval
    >>> new = [literal_eval(v) for inner in a for v in inner.split(",")]
    >>> new
    [1, 0, 1.2, 2, -1.5, 1.2, 3, -1.5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1.5, 1.2]
```

Comment: To be completely true to the OPs example, you'd need a replacement for `float(v)` that returns `float` if the string contains a decimal point and `int` if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my comment with the edit.  That's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `map`,

```
In [1]: l = ['1,0,1.2', '2,-1.5,1.2', '3,-1.5,0', '4,0,0', '5,1.5,1.2']

In [2]: list(map(float, ','.join(l).split(',')))
Out[2]: [1.0, 0.0, 1.2, 2.0, -1.5, 1.2, 3.0, -1.5, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.5, 1.2]
```

Comment: Did you even check your results?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, Just missed out `,` in `join`. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.